# trying to get information from excel to JS

Tags: javascript, excel

I did a currency converter and I put all the currency rates in a .xlsx (excel file), the data is updating and saving itself automatically so I can't save it as .csv and parse the data into the script. I need to know how could I get data directly from excel to JavaScript (I only understand in javascript so if you use another language I'll be glad if you'll send the full code).

This is the site itself:

```css
header 
{
    position: fixed;
    width: 100%;
    top: 0;
    background-image: url(../images/banner-1103703_960_720.jpg);
    box-shadow: 0 0 4px grey;
}

body
{
margin: 0px;
background-color: #6eaac4;
}

#converter
{
padding-top: 230px;
text-align: center;

}
#logo
{
max-width: 340px;
}

#to
{
    font-size: 40px;
    color: firebrick;
    font-family:fantasy;
}

select
{
    width: 300px;
    height: 50px;
    line-height: 50px;
    border-radius: 15px;
    background-color:lightblue;
    font-size: 20px;
}

article
{
    background-color: chartreuse;
       border-radius: 50px;
    border-color: black;
    width: 340px;
    height: auto;
}

button
{
     /* Green */
     background-color:whitesmoke;
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    border: 4px;
    cursor:pointer;
    overflow: hidden;
    border-radius: 30px;
    outline:none;
    color: firebrick;
    text-align: center;
    font-family: fantasy;
    letter-spacing: 5px;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 50px;
}

input
{
    background-color: lightblue;
    border-radius: 15px;
    width: 200px;
    height: 50px;
    line-height: 50px;
    border-width: 1px;
    font-size: 20px;
    text-align: center;
    
    
}

iframe
{
    display: none;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html manifest="offline.manifest">
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="design/style.css">
<link rel="icon" href="images/icon.ico">
<title>Vertycon</title>
    <script src="jquery-3.1.0.min.js" ></script>
</head>
<body onload="">
<header> 
<center><a href="index.html">
<img id="logo" src="images/LOGO.png" height="170px" width="340px">
</a></center> </header>
    <div id="converter">
       <center> <article><br>
           <input type="number" name="amount" placeholder="Amount" id="amount"/>
           <br><br>
           <select id="From">
            <option value="Display">Convert From..</option>
            <option value="US Dollar">US Dollar</option>  
            <option value="ARS"> Argentine Peso</option>
            <option value="AUD">Australian Dollar</option>
            <option value="BHD">Bahraini Dinar</option>
            <option value="BWP">Botswana Pula</option>
            <option value="BRL">Brazilian Real</option>
            <option value="BND">Bruneian Dollar</option>
            <option value="BGN">Bulgarian Lev</option>
            <option value="CAD">Canadian Dollar</option>
            <option value="CLP">Chilean Peso</option>
            <option value="CNY">Chinese Yuan Renminbi</option>
            <option value="COP">Colombian Peso</option>
            <option value="HRK">Croatian Kuna</option>
            <option value="CZK">Czech Koruna</option>
            <option value="DKK">Danish Krone</option>
            <option value="EUR">Euro</option>
            <option value="HKD">Hong Kong Dollar</option>
            <option value="HUF">Hungarian Forint</option>
            <option value="ISK">Icelandic Krona</option>
            <option value="INR">Indian Rupee</option>
            <option value="IDR">Indonesian Rupiah</option>
            <option value="IRR">Iranian Rial</option>
            <option value="ILS">Israeli Shekel</option>
            <option value="JPY">Japanese Yen</option>
            <option value="KZT">Kazakhstani Tenge</option>
            <option value="KRW">South Korean Won</option>
            <option value="KWD">Kuwaiti Dinar</option>
            <option value="LYD">Libyan Dinar</option>
            <option value="MYR">Malaysian Ringgit</option>
            <option value="MUR">Mauritian Rupee</option>
            <option value="MXN">Mexican Peso</option>
            <option value="NPR">Nepalese Rupee</option>
            <option value="NZD">New Zealand Dollar</option>
            <option value="NOK">Norwegian Krone</option>
            <option value="OMR">Omani Rial</option>
            <option value="PKR">Pakistani Rupee</option>
            <option value="JPY">Philippine Peso</option>
            <option value="PLN">Polish Zloty</option>
            <option value="QAR">Qatari Riyal</option>
            <option value="RON">Romanian New Leu</option>
            <option value="RUB">Russian Ruble</option>
            <option value="SAR">Saudi Arabian Riyal</option>
            <option value="SGD">Singapore Dollar</option>
            <option value="ZAR">South African Rand</option>
            <option value="LKR">Sri Lankan Rupee</option>
            <option value="SEK">Swedish Krona</option>
            <option value="CHF">Swiss Franc</option>
            <option value="TWD">Taiwan New Dollar</option>
            <option value="THB">Thai Baht</option>
            <option value="TTD">Trinidadian Dollar</option>
            <option value="TRY">Turkish Lira</option>
            <option value="AED">Emirati Dirham</option>
            <option value="GBP">British Pound</option>
            <option value="VEF">Venezuelan Bolivar</option>
                   </select>
        <div id="to"> &nbsp;To&nbsp;</div> 
     <select id="To">
            <option value="Display">Convert To..</option>
            <option value="USD">US Dollar</option>  
            <option value="ARS"> Argentine Peso</option>
            <option value="AUD">Australian Dollar</option>
            <option value="BHD">Bahraini Dinar</option>
            <option value="BWP">Botswana Pula</option>
            <option value="BRL">Brazilian Real</option>
            <option value="BND">Bruneian Dollar</option>
            <option value="BGN">Bulgarian Lev</option>
            <option value="CAD">Canadian Dollar</option>
            <option value="CLP">Chilean Peso</option>
            <option value="CNY">Chinese Yuan Renminbi</option>
            <option value="COP">Colombian Peso</option>
            <option value="HRK">Croatian Kuna</option>
            <option value="CZK">Czech Koruna</option>
            <option value="DKK">Danish Krone</option>
            <option value="EUR">Euro</option>
            <option value="HKD">Hong Kong Dollar</option>
            <option value="HUF">Hungarian Forint</option>
            <option value="ISK">Icelandic Krona</option>
            <option value="INR">Indian Rupee</option>
            <option value="IDR">Indonesian Rupiah</option>
            <option value="IRR">Iranian Rial</option>
            <option value="ILS">Israeli Shekel</option>
            <option value="JPY">Japanese Yen</option>
            <option value="KZT">Kazakhstani Tenge</option>
            <option value="KRW">South Korean Won</option>
            <option value="KWD">Kuwaiti Dinar</option>
            <option value="LYD">Libyan Dinar</option>
            <option value="MYR">Malaysian Ringgit</option>
            <option value="MUR">Mauritian Rupee</option>
            <option value="MXN">Mexican Peso</option>
            <option value="NPR">Nepalese Rupee</option>
            <option value="NZD">New Zealand Dollar</option>
            <option value="NOK">Norwegian Krone</option>
            <option value="OMR">Omani Rial</option>
            <option value="PKR">Pakistani Rupee</option>
            <option value="JPY">Philippine Peso</option>
            <option value="PLN">Polish Zloty</option>
            <option value="QAR">Qatari Riyal</option>
            <option value="RON">Romanian New Leu</option>
            <option value="RUB">Russian Ruble</option>
            <option value="SAR">Saudi Arabian Riyal</option>
            <option value="SGD">Singapore Dollar</option>
            <option value="ZAR">South African Rand</option>
            <option value="LKR">Sri Lankan Rupee</option>
            <option value="SEK">Swedish Krona</option>
            <option value="CHF">Swiss Franc</option>
            <option value="TWD">Taiwan New Dollar</option>
            <option value="THB">Thai Baht</option>
            <option value="TTD">Trinidadian Dollar</option>
            <option value="TRY">Turkish Lira</option>
            <option value="AED">Emirati Dirham</option>
            <option value="GBP">British Pound</option>
            <option value="VEF">Venezuelan Bolivar</option>
        </select>
        <br>
        <br>
        <button type="submit" id="submit" onclick="Vars; Alert();">Convert!</button>
        <br>
        <br>
        <br>
        <br>
            </article></center>
    </div>
    <iframe src="https://onedrive.live.com/embed?cid=BE27105A8171337A&resid=BE27105A8171337A%211291&authkey=ALjfySLkSxTD7MU&em=2" width="402" height="346" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" id="ifrm"></iframe>
   
    <script>
function Vars(){
 var select1 = document.getElementById('From');
  var From = (select1.options[select.selectedIndex]);
  var select2 = document.getElementById('To');
  var To = (select2.options[select.selectedIndex]);
}
        function Alert(){
            alert(From.value+To.value)
            alert(document.getElementById('amount').value)
        }
    </script>
   
    

</body>
</html>
```

and this is the excel file:

[the excel file](https://1drv.ms/x/s!AnozcYFaECe-igtiopLfzQQfE44H)

Thanks from advance,
love u guys

Comment: where is your excel document getting the data from? It must be some sort of API. it might be a lot easier to hit that API directly with js than trying to work from the excel spreadsheet

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of libraries that accomplish this. The one I've used for my company is [SheetJS](http://sheetjs.com/).

EDIT: Adding an example. This is a stripped-down version of a utility function which takes in a file and a set of properties to parse the data from an excel sheet into a more usable form.

```
var REGEX = { 'regexExcel': /^.+\.(xlsx?)$/i, 'regexExcelWithOds: /^.+\.((?:xlsx?)|(?:ods))$/i };

/**
 * Converts an excel column letter (e.g. R, AZ) to an associated integer
 * value so that it can be used as an iterator
 **/
function excelColumnToInt (index)
{
  var multiplier = 1, value = 0;

  for (var iterator = (index.length - 1); iterator >= 0; iterator--)
  {
    if (multiplier === 1)
    {
      //'A' is 65 in ASCII. It equates to 0 for our purposes.
      value += (index.charCodeAt (iterator) - 65);
    }
    else
    {
      value += (index.charCodeAt (iterator) - 64) * multiplier;
    }

    multiplier *= 26;
  }

  return value;
}

/**
 * Retrieves the letter of the column associated with the given field name
 **/
function excelGetColumnForProperty (worksheet, fieldName, bounds)
{
  var column;

  for (var count = bounds[0].c; count <= bounds[1].c; count++)
  {
    column = excelIntToColumn(count);

    try
    {
      if (worksheet[column + bounds[0].r].v.trim ().toLowerCase () === fieldName.toLowerCase ())
      {
        return column;
      }
    }
    catch (exception)
    {
      continue;
    }
  }

  return null;
}

/**
 * Validates a given excel document against its given fields, then feeds the
 * result to the given callback function
 **/
function importFromExcel (filepicker, properties, callback)
{
  var processing = true;

  var files = $(filepicker)[0].files;

  if (!files.length)
  {
    //Raise error notification here

    processing = false;

    return;
  }

  if (!properties || !properties.length)
  {
    processing = false;

    return;
  }

  var errorMessage;
  var errorList = [], itemSet = [];
  var workbook, extensionCheck;
  var reader = new FileReader ();

  //Handler is created before iterating through the files
  reader.onload = function (event)
  {
    try
    {
      switch (extensionCheck[1])
      {
        case 'xls':
          workbook = XLS.read (event.target.result, {type: 'binary'});

          break;
        case 'ods':
          //NOTE: Has some issues with parsing sparse sheets
          workbook = XLSX.read (event.target.result, {type: 'binary'});

          break;
        default:
          workbook = XLSX.read (event.target.result, {type: 'binary'});
      }
    }
    catch (exception)
    {
      //Raise error notification here

      processing = false;

      return;
    }

    var sheet, ref, bounds, tmp, count, match;

    workbook.SheetNames.forEach (function (sheetname, sheetIndex)
    {
      sheet = workbook.Sheets[sheetname];

      //Skip empty worksheets
      if (!sheet['!ref']) { return; }

      //Format: A1:ZZ99
      ref = sheet['!ref'].split (':');
      bounds = [];

      //Low bound
      tmp = ref[0].match (/^([A-Z]+)([0-9]+)$/);
      bounds[0] = {c: excelColumnToInt (tmp[1]), r: parseInt(tmp[2])};

      //High bound
      tmp = ref[1].match (/^([A-Z]+)([0-9]+)$/);
      bounds[1] = {c: excelColumnToInt (tmp[1]), r: parseInt(tmp[2])};

      //Cycle through the last row. If content is not found, reduce the
      //bound and try the next row up
      var checkingBounds = true;

      while (checkingBounds)
      {
        for (count = 0; count < bounds[1].c; count++)
        {
          try
          {
            if (!!sheet[excelIntToColumn (count) + bounds[1].r].w)
            {
              checkingBounds = false;
              bounds[1].r++;
              break;
            }
          }
          catch (exception)
          {
            //Fail silently
          }
        }

        bounds[1].r--;
      }

      //Find the column associated with each property
      properties.forEach (function (property, propertyIndex)
      {
        property.column = excelGetColumnForProperty (sheet, property.name, bounds);

        //Column with the given name not found
        if (!property.column)
        {
          errorList.push ('Could not find a column corresponding to <strong>' + property.name + '</strong> on <strong>' + sheetname + '</strong>');
        }
      });

      if (!!errorList.length) { return; }

      //Retrieve product data
      var itemObj;
      var rowValid = true;

      for (count = (bounds[0].r + 1); count <= bounds[1].r; count++)
      {
        itemObj = {};
        rowValid = true;

        properties.forEach (function (property, propertyIndex)
        {
          try
          {
            if (property.required && sheet[property.column + count] === undefined)
            {
              throw 'Required property missing';
            }

            //Define custom handlers based on expected inputs
            switch (property.handler)
            {
              case 'myHandler':

                break;
              default:
                itemObj[property.field] = sheet[property.column + count].v;
            }
          }
          catch (exception)
          {
            //Guard in case the flattened sheet is missing an index associated with an optional value
            if (exception === 'Required property missing' && property.required)
            {
              errorList.push ('Could not find a value for <strong>' + property.name + '</strong> on <strong>' + sheetname + '</strong> at <strong>row ' + count + '</strong>. This is a required field.');
              rowValid = false;
            }
          }
        });

        if (rowValid)
        {
          itemSet.push (itemObj);
        }
      }
    });

    if (!!errorList.length)
    {
      errorMessage = '<p>The system encountered issues when trying to read your file. Please fix these problems before proceeding.</p><ul>';

      errorList.forEach (function (error, index)
      {
        errorMessage += '<li>' + error + '</li>';
      });

      errorMessage += '</ul>';

      //Notify user of the errors you encountered here

      processing = false;
    }
    else
    {
      callback (itemSet);
    }
  };

  var count, file;

  //Note: Only one file is supported at this time, but the structure
  //      for handling multiple files is the same. Support for multiple
  //      files results in a fairly complicated synchronization model.
  for (count = 0; count < files.length; count++)
  {
    file = files[count];

    extensionCheck = file.name.match (REGEX.regexExcel);

    if (!extensionCheck)
    {
      //ODS files don't seem to parse correctly
      errorList.push ('The file ' + file.name + ' is invalid. Please provide a .xls or a .xlsx file.');

      continue;
    }

    reader.readAsBinaryString (file);
  }

  if (!!errorList.length)
  {
    errorMessage = '<p>The system encountered issues when trying to read your file. Please fix these problems before proceeding.</p><ul>';

    errorList.forEach (function (error, index)
    {
      errorMessage += '<li>' + error + '</li>';
    });

    errorMessage += '</ul>';

    //Notify user of parsing errors here

    processing = false;
  }
}
```

**Example Usage:**

```
importFromExcel ('#myFilePicker',
                 [
                   {field: 'name', name: 'Name', handler: 'assignment', required: true},
                   {field: 'is_taxed', name: 'Taxable (Y/N)', handler: 'boolean', required: false}
                 ],
                 function (results)
                 {
                   //Handle the response here
                 });
```

Comment: can you explain how to use it?

Comment: Actually it doesn't matters, I tried to use this and the data doesn't appear. I think it's because of the web data in the document..

Comment: Added a fairly comprehensive example. The main limitation is that the column headings must be on the first row of the spreadsheet, but they can be in any order, and each can be given a unique handler.